# App Store Upload Gives Warning; WARNING ITMS-90686: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

After uploading an app bundle to the App Store, a dialog is shown with the following warning:

```
WARNING ITMS-90686: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
```

The app does get accepted by the app store, and it can be installed through TestFlight without any issues.

The only change made to the application was setting Build Active Architectures only from YES to NO (for Release). Initially there was an issue with a CocoaPod still having that setting set to YES, but despite fixing that the warning is still returned. There are no warnings in Xcode's build issues view.

Comment: I've been getting the error all day and ignoring it. Everything seems to be working anyway.

Comment: Related thread in apple forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a temporary issue with the App Store and can safely be ignored if your app showed up in TestFlight.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incorrect I'm afraid.

This isn't an AppStore issue, the reason for the error is because in your APP has a CFBundleDocumentTypes that uses a "LSItemContentTypes" without a defined type for "LSHandlerRank" item in it's info.plist configuration.

To fix:

1) Use XCODE to navigate into your info.plist file

2) Right-click and select "View as source code"

3) Search for CFBundleDocumentTypes

4) You should end up with something like the code below:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

5) Add the following items to tell AppStore that the document type (in this example) of "com.apple.maps.directionsrequest" is "Default" which means that "your APP reads it but isn't the creator of this type"

```
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Default</string>
```

6) Save the file, 
7) Upload again, should work fine.

More information on the types of items can be found on the App Store page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1

I hope this explains the error and how to resolve it.

It's working on mine fine, this is the latest changes XCODE that needs to be clarified.